# Allow network services running in different Docker containers to see each other

Tags: docker, keycloak, activemq-artemis

I want to integrate Keycloak and ActiveMQ Artemis, but both are running in different Docker containers. What IP should in mention in Keycloak json files, what should be the redirect URL in Keycloak console?
[Keycloak json file I used](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/examples/features/standard/security-keycloak/src/main/resources/activemq/server0)

- Artemis Version - 2.17.1
- Keycloak version - 21.0.1

I have put all the libraries in lib folder of broker, added java args in `artemis.profile`. (All the changes in active has been done, it works on local)

Lets say my Keycloak Docker IP is `172.17.0.3`, in the json files I mentioned `172.17.0.3`:

```
{
    "realm"    : "artemis-keycloak-demo",
    "clientId" : "artemis-console",
    "url"      : "http://172.17.0.3:8080"
}
```

I tried giving **localhost** as well

When I mention Docker IP, and I hit `localhost:8161` it is not redirected to Keycloak console.

When I mention `localhost:8080` it redirects to Keycloak, a session is created in Keycloak (I can see in Keycloak console), but then give error in ActiveMQ Artemis.

I have created a network, and while running both images I'm using `--net 'network-name'`. So, I guess they are on same network for ActiveMQ Artemis exposed `8161` for console and for Keycloak `8080`.

Comment: Do you use docker-compose or how are you starting both containers? You probably want to ensure they are on the same network in docker and use their dns names instead of localhost in the config

Comment: I have created a network, and while running both images I'm using --net 'network-name'. So, i guess they are on same network
for activemq exposed 8161 for console and for keycloak 8080

Comment: Given that this works _without_ Docker this question seems much more like a Docker configuration issue than a Keycloak or ActiveMQ Artemis configuration issue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. This cannot be just a Docker configuration issue as URLs to be configured in JSON files of Keycloak are more on the integration side.

Comment: From what I can tell you use the default ports, so I would focus on the domain name part. You write, that you tried `localhost:8080`, but that only works from the host machine, where docker is running. Inside the docker network each container has their own (dns) name. This is what you should use, e.g. `my-keycloak:8080`. `docker ps` should give you the right name. You can also try pinging the other container from a shell inside the container, e.g. `docker exec my-artemis bash` (or something like that)